# Unknown warning appearing on validation of invoice odoo

Tags: odoo

I am trying to validate the customer invoice, once i click the validate button it display the below warning:

[image]

I am getting this as soon as i click to validate the customer invoice created from a sales order. I have tried upgrading modules of account and account_voucher, but still no success.

Can anyone explain the reason of getting this error or provide any solution to it?

Comment: Probably some usererror returning list instead of string. Past e your code here

Comment: there is no customization, its a default version

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.